# Is there any optimal way to find distinct values in 2 arrayList

Tags: java, optimization

I am trying to find a optimal way to find distinct elements in 2 arrayLists which contains map in it.

Ex. a1 and a2 are arraylists where

- a1 = [{"val":"1","id":"19"},{"val":"2","id":"22"},{"val":"3","id":"2"},{"val":"4","id":"49"}]
- a2 = [{"val":"1","id":"12"},{"val":"2","id":"22"},{"val":"3","id":"32"},{"val":"5","id":"52"}]

Expected output is:

- lOld = [{"val":"5","id":"52"}]
- lNew = [{"val":"4","id":"49"}]

My solution for the problem is:

```
List<Map<String, String>> lOld = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < a1.size(); j++) {
        if(a2.get(i).get("val").equals(a1.get(j).get("val"))){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == false){
        lOld.add(a2.get(i));
    }
}

List<Map<String, String>> lNew = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {
        if(a1.get(i).get("val").equals(a2.get(j).get("val"))){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == false){
        lNew.add(a1.get(i));
    }
}
```

Is there any optimal way to solve this problem?

Note: Map inside arrayList contains more then one value. a1 and a2 are just taken for an example.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Find the uncommon elements from two sets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/find-the-uncommon-elements-from-two-sets)

Answer (score 0):

- Convert ArrayLists to HashSets

  - this gives you O(1) for set.contains()
- Use Map.equals() to check if 2 maps have the same key-value pairs or not (i.e. check if contents are same)

Now you can iterate over one set and check if that element is present in the other set. This will give you linear time instead of quadratic

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve this problem:

1. merge maps from arrayList a1 to map lOld,merge maps from arrayList a2 to map lNew
2. fetch keySets from both lOld Map and lNew Map
3. Add common keys from both keysets into temporary arrayList
4. remove this temporary arrayList from both keySets.
5. if you want output in arrayList form, add lOld and lNew maps into newly created arrayLists

[demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/FTDhYM)

```java
        // start- get arrayList a1 index entries, fetch map,put all maps into one map to 
        //remove duplicate keys,doesn't matter value- because they will be removed anyways)
        Map<String, String> lOld = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> a1Map = a1.get(i);
            lOld.putAll(a1Map);
        }
        //end

        // start- get arrayList a2 index entries, fetch map,put all maps into other map to remove
        // duplicate keys,doesn't matter value- because they will be removed anyways)

        HashMap<String, String> lNew = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> a2Map = a2.get(j);
            lNew.putAll(a2Map);
        }
       //end

        // check if first map keys (set) is in second map keys (set). 
       //if yes, add them into a list.
        List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> oldKeys = lOld.keySet();
        Set<String> newKeys = lNew.keySet();
        for (String oldKey : oldKeys) {
            if (lNew.containsKey(oldKey)) {
                toRemove.add(oldKey);
            }
        }

        // remove that list elements from both sets which will remove them from map itself.
        oldKeys.removeAll(toRemove);
        newKeys.removeAll(toRemove);

        // print both map
        System.out.println("lold map is: " + lOld);
        System.out.println("lNew map is: " + lNew);

        // don't remove elements from set while iterating. it will give ConcurrentModificationException
```

Answer (score -1):

Best performance for finding item in a collection is using HashSet.

Check it out here : 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashset-arraylist-contains-performance